# Getting the port number of a server through a browser

Tags: c, webserver

I have a `server.c` I can connect to it if I know the port that I assign to the server; lets say 6000. I go to FireFox and type `127.0.0.1:6000` and I can connect perfectly.

How do I build my server that a client will type 127.0.0.1 on a browser and then the server will assign the port or notify the user on the browser to type the port?

Perhaps I don't fully understand servers but it seems to me that the client must know the port from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a port to connect. HTTP connects to port 80 by default and that's why you can get away by typing 127.0.0.1 into your browser.

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP was looking for.. that http://127.0.0.1 is equivalent to http://127.0.0.1:80 in the world of http.

Comment: What happens if I want to assign a port myself that is not `80`?

Comment: Your server needs to be listening at that port or else the connection would fail.

Comment: Normally, a server would be listening at a predetermined port (you can find a list of ports used by different application on google). Once the client establishes a connection to that port, the server might spin off a new thread and direct the client to another port so it can keep its own default port open in case another client is also trying to connect. This will allow multiple clients to connect at the same time.

Comment: Yep that's what I was thinking just now. I'll wait on 80 then switch to something appropriate.

Comment: If this is production code, I would recommend against using a lower numbered port, especially something as 80. Go with something like 42123.

Answer (score 0):

The default standard port is 80 for an IP in a browser. Maybe your program (server.c) waits a request with the default port 80, and transfer the request into another user-defined port.